# DynamoDB write and read in one operation

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Is there a way to write/update something to a row and query the row in one round trip for dynamodb? The idea is I want to conditional write into a row but if the conditional write fails, I want to query an attribute.

Comment: Can you provide a sample usecase of what you want? Dynamo does support conditional writes but I am not sure it exactly meets your needs.http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.ConditionalUpdate

Comment: @Shibashis Okay for example, lets' say my row has 2 attributes, name and price. I want to increase the price but only if it's below 10. So I do a conditional write stating that I want to change it to 20 only if it's 10. Now in addition, if the conditional write fails, I want to know the name (1st attribute). Currently, I do this by first conditionally writing and if that fails, I query the row to get the name (hence 2 round trips). Is there a way to do a write (doesn't have to be conditional) but then read as well? So atomic write-then-read. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think dynamo API supports that. The API throws an exception, whatever you have implemented is best way to do it.